# Adding an index via LINQ to Windows Phone database

Tags: windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql

We have a C# Windows Phone application and I am trying to make use of dbschemaupdater.AddIndex().
However, I am unsure of how to define the fields associated with the index and cannot find any online examples that seem relevant.

Our database tables are defined as classes via SQLMetal, e.g.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name = "PDA_AppActiveLog")]
public partial class PDA_AppActiveLog : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    [Column(IsVersion = true)]
    private Binary version;


    private int _AppActiveLogID;

    private DateTime _EventTime;

    private string _EventCode;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();

    partial void OnAppActiveLogIDChanging(int value);
    partial void OnAppActiveLogIDChanged();

    partial void OnEventTimeChanging(DateTime value);
    partial void OnEventTimeChanged();

    partial void OnEventCodeChanging(string value);
    partial void OnEventCodeChanged();

    #endregion

    public PDA_AppActiveLog()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_AppActiveLogID", AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]

    public int AppActiveLogID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._AppActiveLogID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._AppActiveLogID != value))
            {
                this.OnAppActiveLogIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._AppActiveLogID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("AppActiveLogID");
                this.OnAppActiveLogIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_EventTime", DbType = "DateTime NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime EventTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this._EventTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._EventTime != value))
            {
                this.OnEventTimeChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._EventTime = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("EventTime");
                this.OnEventTimeChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_EventCode", DbType = "NVarChar(30)", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never, CanBeNull = true)]
    public string EventCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this._EventCode;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._EventCode != value))
            {
                this.OnEventCodeChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._EventCode = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("EventCode");
                this.OnEventCodeChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


}
```

Within our code, we add something like:

```
            if (dbSchema.DatabaseSchemaVersion == 8)
            {
                dbSchema.AddTable<PDA_AppActiveLog>();
                dbSchema.DatabaseSchemaVersion = 9;

                //dbSchema.AddIndex<PDA_AppActiveLog>("EventCode");
                dbSchema.Execute();
                dbSchema = dc.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();
            }
```

However, I am unsure how to define which fields belong to the new index.

It seems from this article, that the functionality is there:
http://justinangel.net/AllWp7MangoAPIs#linq2sql

However, all the examples I've seen show the database definition code differently, e.g.:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394022(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Preparingversion3Addinganindexconsideringmultipleupgradepaths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394022%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Preparingversion3Addinganindexconsideringmultipleupgradepaths)

```
// Index added in version 3 of the application.
[Index(Columns = "Priority", Name = "PriorityIndex")]
```

I am unsure if I can make equivalent changes, but even if I am, then I can no longer use SQLMetal to pre-generate the classes unless I want to modify them everytime afterwards?

What is the best way to get an index added?

Thanks.